# Printing text box value on page in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP (in-fact I am learning it). I am trying to get the value of textbox defined in HTML and print it on HTML page through PHP code. I am able to send the value of textbox to another page using form post and getting it using `$_POST['name']` on other page.

I am not able to print the value of textbox on same page.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php

            function myfunction()
            {
                printf($_POST['fname']);
            }

        ?>
    </head>

    <body>

        Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />

        <input type="button" onClick="myfunction()" value="Click" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is server side, and therefore you can't access functions from JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I figured it what I was doing wrong. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's not required to write  php function within `<head>` tags. Second, 
you can't POST data without `<form>` tags. try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit'){
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
     echo $name;
     }
else {  
        ?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can not call PHP function by button's click event...

if you want to print on same page then you can do by below code..

```
<html>
    <?php
        if(count($_POST)>0){
            echo $_POST['fname'];
        }
    ?>
<body>
  <form method='post'>
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />

    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

hope you will get what you want by my answer..

Comment: `onClick="myfunction()"` what is that? how can you post data without any form?

Comment: do you know PHP at all? Where do you posting data? Where is `action`?

Comment: If you leave action blank, data will be posted to same page :)
need not to add action everytime, if you have db function call on the same page then you can leave action blank.